# Как правильно - эксплоит или эксплойт?

Tags: переводы

Как правильно писать? Гугл переводчик переводит через `й`, а один знакомый говорит что правильно через `и`:

> эксплоит — через обычную и, как андроид.

Так как правильно писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слова "андроид", "гуманоид" и аналогичные заимствованные слова с -оид- образуют устойчивую фонетическую и смысловую группу (произносятся без "йот"). Нет оснований для проведения аналогии между -оид ("греческое" окончание сложных слов значением "подобный) и -ойт в слове "**эксплойт**": 1) для русского не характерно сочетание -оит- с ударным "о", 2) в языке заимствования гласные в сочетании -ойт произносятся общим дифтонгом.

Для сравнения: по этим же двум основаниям *неверно* навязываемое журналистикой "биткойн" вместо "**биткоин**": 1) едва ли не единственная похожесть в русском - "войн" (род. падеж); 2) в исходном языке гласные слова coin (англ. монета) не сливаются в дифтонг.

Comment: Так и не понятно, какое слово использовать?

Comment: Слово с буквой "Й". Как "брандсбойт".

Comment: @Alex_ander, так я и не понял: какой вариант вы рекомендуете писать: с ***и*** или с  ***й*** ?

Comment: C и кратким, как написал.

Answer (score 1):

Орфографической рекомендации пока нет. Но сегодня в статьях об этой программе, можно встретить оба варианта.

**Эксплойт, эксплоит, сплоит (англ. exploit, эксплуатировать)** — компьютерная программа, фрагмент программного кода или последовательность команд, использующие уязвимости в программном обеспечении и применяемые для проведения атаки на вычислительную систему.

[Википедия](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/36735#.D0.9A.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.81.D0.B8.D1.84.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0.D1.86.D0.B8.D1.8F)

Answer (score 0):

На русском правильно писать примерно так: "вредоносный код, эксплуатирующий уязвимости программного обеспечения". Слово **эксплои(й)т** жаргонное и пока не вошло в словари, поэтому вы со знакомым вправе выбрать для себя тот вариант, который больше нравится, а потом "история вас рассудит".

Я бы выбрал вариант **эксплойт**, поскольку в русском языке есть хоть какие-то слова, основа которых заканчивается на **ойт** (брандспойт, войт — пусть они и не из английского), в то время как **оит** в конце встречается только в словах с суффиксом **ит**, который здесь неуместен.